# Swift: Slice startIndex always 0

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, slice

I ran afoul of Swift Slice, thinking that firstIndex should be the first index of the slice, in the domain of the source (not sure what else it's useful for).  Evidently this is not the case:

```
let ary = map(1...100) { i in i }

let s:Slice<Int> = ary[10..<20]
s.startIndex            // 0
ary[10..<20].startIndex // 0

(10..<20).startIndex    // 10 (half-open interval generated from a range, presumably)
```

Does this seem like a bug?  If it's always 0, it seems totally useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** The following applies to Swift 2 or earlier. The behavior has changed since Swift 2.

If you dig around in the auto-generated Swift header file (where it seems most of the documentation is at the moment), you'll find this describing `Slice`:

```
/// The `Array`-like type that represents a sub-sequence of any
/// `Array`, `ContiguousArray`, or other `Slice`.
```

Since `Slice` is `Array`-like, it does make sense that `startIndex` would be returning `0` since an `Array`'s `startIndex` is always going to be `0`. Further down, where it defines `startIndex`, you'll also see:

```
/// Always zero, which is the index of the first element when non-empty.
var startIndex: Int { get }
```

If you're looking for the first entry in the `Slice`, just use: `s.first`:

```
/// The first element, or `nil` if the array is empty
var first: T? { get }
```

If you need to find the index in the original `Array` that where the `Slice` starts, you can do something like this:

```
if let startValue = s.first {
    let index = find(ary, startValue)
    /* ... do something with index ... */
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  I thought I read though that it was more of a "shallow copy" - kept a reference to the array.  I did end up using the approach that you mentioned, but not by choice.  I still think this is poorly conceived, you lose information, and gain nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in Swift 2. If you slice an array with a range of `2...5`, the startIndex of the slice will be 2. Very cool.

Comment: Well this is pretty useless. A slice is a window, therefore it should have its own index range starting at 0.

Comment: Having just gone through learning the hard way that `data.subdata(0..<32)` doesn't actually return the first 32 bytes of data in swift 5, it pains me to see that it used to be that simple but now it isn't. Well, my `Extensions.swift` file has just grown a few more lines. Bleh.